# Can scipy.integrate.fixed_quad compute integral with functional boundaries?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I would like to numerically integrate function over a triangle similarly as

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
inside = lambda x: integrate.quad(lambda x,y: 1, 0, x, args=(x))[0]
outside = integrate.quad(inside, 0, 1)[0]
print(outside)
0.5
```

but using `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad` function (which has integration order `n` as parameter). However, when I write

```
inside = lambda x: integrate.fixed_quad(lambda x,y: 1, 0, x, args=(x), n=5)
print(inside(5))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/
>   quadrature.py", line 82, in fixed_quad
>       return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=0), None
>
> TypeError: () argument after * must be an iterable, not int

I don't know what I'm doing wrong as I'm following the documentation on [scipy.integrate.fixed_quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your definition of `args`, `args=(x)`. It should be passed as a tuple, so you need to add an additional comma to make it a tuple:

```
inside = lambda x: integrate.fixed_quad(lambda x,y: 1, 0, x, args=(x,), n=5)
```

Then

```
inside(5)
```

yields

```
(5.0, None)
```

The line

```
integrate.quad(lambda x,y: 1, 0, x, args=(x))[0]
```

works as in `quad` it is checked whether `args` is a tuple; if not it is converted (directly taken from the source code):

```
if not isinstance(args, tuple):
        args = (args,)
```

In `fixed_quad` that is not the case and that's why you received the error in one but not both cases.

Comment: Interesting, haven't thought of that as it worked for integrate.quad without a comma. However performing 'outside = integrate.fixed_quad(inside, 0, 1, n=5)[0]' gives another ValueError, so I am still unable to compute the double integral. It works with 'integrate.quad(inside, 0, 1)' though, but I would prefer having n (Gaussian quadrature integration order) parameter in both integrals.

Comment: @Jan: I edited my post with information why it does not crash when `quad` is called.