# Is it possible to compute double integral using scipy.integrate.fixed_quad?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to compute a double integral (over a triangle with nodes at (0,0), (0,1), (1,0)) using Gaussian quadrature of order `n`. However, running

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
f = lambda x,y: x+y
inside = lambda x: integrate.fixed_quad(f, 0, 1-x, args=(x,), n=5)[0]
outside = integrate.fixed_quad(inside, 0, 1, n=5)
```

gives

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 82, in fixed_quad
>       return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=0), None
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 78, in fixed_quad
>       if np.isinf(a) or np.isinf(b):
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This is the second part of the question [Can scipy.integrate.fixed_quad compute integral with functional boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42270420/7573934).

Comment: are you looking for [double integrals](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html#scipy.integrate.dblquad)?

Comment: @kazemakase I'm trying to implement double integrals with parameter n, which is called Gaussian quadrature integration order. Double integrals can be computed using `scipy.integrate.dblquad()` but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you write down the integral you try to solve?

Comment: @Cleb int_0^1 int_0^(x-1) f(x,y) dy dx (integration of function f(x,y) over the triangle with nodes (0,0), (0,1), (1,0))

Comment: using dblquad: `result = integrate.dblquad(f, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1-x)[0]`

Comment: According to the docs this function returns 2 values the estimated value and None where a proper quadrature would return an error estimate. You have to discard the None at least in `inside`.

Comment: @Paul Pannzer thanks, I have edited the post. Same `ValueError` remains unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is, yes, under certain conditions.

For demonstration purposes, I first choose different bounds than you (`11` instead of `1 - x`).

Generally, one can solve these types of integrals using `dblquad`:

```
area_dblquad = integrate.dblquad(lambda x, y: x + y, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 11)[0]
```

which here returns `66`. That is not an option as you mentioned in the comments.

One can now do this integration stepwise and it works fine for `quad` as well as `fixed_quad`:

```
def integrand(x, y):
    return x + y

def fint_quad(x):
    return integrate.quad(integrand, 0, 11, args=(x, ))[0]

def fint_fixed_quad(x):
    return integrate.fixed_quad(integrand, 0, 11, args=(x, ), n=5)[0]

res_quad = integrate.quad(lambda x: fint_quad(x), 0, 1)
res_fixed_quad = integrate.fixed_quad(lambda x: fint_fixed_quad(x), 0, 1, n=5)
```

They both return `66` as well, as expected. That shows that it can work to compute double integrals using `scipy.integrate.fixed_quad`.

However, when one now changes the upper bound back to the one you had (from `11` to `1 - x`), it still works for `quad` but crashes for `fixed_quad`:

```
area_dblquad = integrate.dblquad(lambda x, y: x + y, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1 - x)[0]
res_quad = integrate.quad(lambda x: fint_quad(x), 0, 1)
```

both return `0.333333...`, the call with `fixed_quad` results in the error you received. One can understand the error by looking on the source code:

```
x, w = _cached_roots_legendre(n)
x = np.real(x)
if np.isinf(a) or np.isinf(b):
    raise ValueError("Gaussian quadrature is only available for "
                         "finite limits.")
y = (b-a)*(x+1)/2.0 + a
return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=-1), None
```

When one prints `a` and `b` one gets:

```
a:  0
b:  1
a:  0
b:  [ 0.95308992  0.76923466  0.5         0.23076534  0.04691008]
```

So for the call with `1-x`, `b` is actually a numpy array with `n` elements and one cannot compare an array to infinity, that's why it crashes. Whether that is an intended behavior or a bug, I can't answer; might be worth opening an issue on github.

Comment: That's a NumPy array, not a list.

Comment: As for whether it's a bug, no. `fixed_quad` [documents](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html) that the function you integrate "must accept vector inputs", which `inside` does not.

Comment: @user2357112: Could very well be; but would it then not be printed as `array(...)`? But no matter whether it is a numpy array or a list, it still leads to the same issue when compared to infinity. 
Ah, very well spotted, thanks! I overlooked this part in the documentation.

Comment: It wouldn't be printed as `array(...)` with just  `print`. You'd have to do `print(repr(...))` to get the `repr` instead of `str` output.

Answer (score 0):

`fixed_quad` requires `f` to accept vector inputs. And the result should be the mapped values for the inputs (i.e. something like `map(f, xs)`). With this in mind, just ensure your `inside` function returns mapped values, and you're ready to go.

```py
import scipy.integrate as integrate
f = lambda y,x: x+y
inside = lambda xs, n: np.array([integrate.fixed_quad(f, 0, 1-x, args=(x,), n=n)[0]
                                 for x in np.array(xs)])
order = 5
outside = integrate.fixed_quad(inside, 0, 1, n=order, args=(order,))
```

Also, be careful with the order of arguments for your integrand. Judging from your code `arg=(x,)`, it seems that you want the inner integral to be done along y dimension. The first argument of the integrand is the dimension along which it is integrated. So it should be `lambda y,x` instead (note that this is also the shape of integrand expected by `dblquad`).